# Find previous week/month/quarter number from current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get last week, last month and last quarter numbers (appended with year number) based on current date.

I have used CONCAT and IIF to get current week/month/quarter numbers and substract it with -1, then check if it is last month/quarter to handle 0 values. Below is the code to get last month and quarter, however I am looking for an optimised code to make it work better. Also getting last week number using code similar to below will have issue with leap/non-leap years.

Last month:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),IIF(DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())-1=0,12,DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())-1))
```

Last quarter:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),IIF(DATEPART(QUARTER,GETDATE())-1=0,4,DATEPART(QUARTER,GETDATE())-1))
```

For example, If my current date is 4th Jan, 2019 - 
Last week should return 52 or 53 (based on leap year), Last month should return 12, Last quarter should return 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
--a week ago
select DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETUTCDATE())

--the week number(of year), a week ago
select DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETUTCDATE()))

--a month ago
select DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETUTCDATE())

--the month number, a month ago
select DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETUTCDATE()))

--a quarter ago
select DATEADD(QUARTER, -1, GETUTCDATE())

--the quarter number, a quarter ago
select DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEADD(QUARTER, -1, GETUTCDATE()))
```

General formula is thus:

Day and time, some PERIOD (week, month, quarter, year etc) ago:

```
DATEADD(PERIOD_IDENTIFIER, -NUMBER_OF_PERIODS, CURRENT_DATE)
```

The period that it was then:

```
DATEPART(PERIOD_IDENTIFIER, DATEADD(PERIOD_IDENTIFIER, -NUMBER_OF_PERIODS, CURRENT_DATE))
```

ps; every year has 53 weeks, not just leap years, because 365/7 is fractionally over 52

pps; I've used GetUtcDate above because I typically work in UTC as most of my tasks are on multi-country systems and all times are UTC. If you're specifically after something that reports "last X" for your local timezone you might need to use GetDate() instead so that the concept of "this week" and "last week" etc is aligned with your local concept of midnight/day changing

Comment: Why are you using `GETUTCDATE` instead of `GETDATE`?

Comment: Force of habit; I always work on international systems and all dates are UTC. I'll add a note about it

Answer (score 0):

Use this in SQL Server.

```
select  datepart(mm,getdate()-30) as Last_Month
       ,datepart(qq, getdate()-7) as Last_Quarter
       ,datepart(wk,getdate()-7) as Last_Week
```